# Second Order Quantification without Ontological Commitment

Tags: reference-request

I've seen some philosophers allude to second order quantification without ontologically committing to the second order predicates quantified over. However, I'm struggling to find papers discussing this question. Could anyone point in the right direction for papers/chapters to read on this?

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I found the following discussion of a positive answer to the question of non-ontologically committing second order quantification:

[Nominalism through De-Nominalization (2001), by Rayo, A. & Yablo, S.](https://philpapers.org/rec/RAYNTD)